# What's my full version 7.1 (11D167)

Tags: ios, iphone, versions

I'm trying to figure out if I'm on IOS 7.1, 7.1.1, or just what?  I get 7.1 (11D167).  I'm thinking to attempt to use ["pangu"](http://www.evad3rs.net/2014/06/pangu-download-links-for-iphone-ipad.html) to jailbreak my phone.

Comment: Pangu Jailbreak works on iOS 7.1 to 7.1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11D167 is **iOS 7.1**.

The version shown in the device About will show the entire version number.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what version you're using, just as long as you're running a version of  ios 7.1 then you're good to go. I've jailbroken my iPhone using pangu. make sure you back up regularly as some files on cydia may not agree with you're devices coding :)